# Printing escape characters from strings read in from the command line in c

Tags: c, posix, c-strings, ansi-escape

---

I am trying to write a small echo program named echo as defined [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/echo.html) in C using only the C STD library and C Posix library based on the SUSv4 description of what a posix echo program should do. However I am hitting a snag when testing my parsing of escape codes.

My algorithm was simple just cycle through string characters arrays checking each character looking for '\' as in the following snippet:

```
for(innerloop = 0;innerloop < strlen(singlestring);innerloop++)
{
    if(singlestring[innerloop] == '\\' && innerloop + 1 < strlen(singlestring))
    {
        switch(singlestring[innerloop+1])
        {
            case 'a':
                    printf("\a");
                    break;
            case 'b':
                    printf("\b");
                    break;
            case 'c':
                    cescape = 1;
                    innerloop = strlen(singlestring);
                    break;
            case 'f':
                    printf("\f");
                    break;
            case 'n':
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
            case 'r':
                    printf("\r");
                    break;
            case 't':
                    printf("\t");
                    break;
            case 'v':
                    printf("\v");
                    break;
            case '0':
                    /*not implemented yet*/
                    break;
            default: /*character = '\\'*/
                   printf("\\");
                   innerloop--;
                   break;
        }
        innerloop++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c",singlestring[innerloop]);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for most applications however my troubles being when I start debugging the logic of the escape codes the '\' one in particular. If I pass to my program from the command line:

```
echo "Hello\nWorld"
```

The results are as expected:

```
Hello
World
```

However when I add extra '\' to the string:

```
echo "Hello\\nWorld"
```

The results were unexpected to me as I expected the output to be "Hello\nWorld" but my baseline of gnu echo and busybox echo seemingly agreed.

```
Hello
World
```

The point of divergence however comes after multiple '\'

```
echo "Hello\\\nWorld"
```

My results:

```
Hello\
World
```

Gnu/Busybox's echo results

```
Hello\nWorld
```

The pattern now repeats itself just adding more '\' characters.

Is my algorithm fundamentally flawed and not in line with the POSIX specification or are the GNU and Busybox echo programs not following the POSIX standard or is it some combination of the two?

Comment: Your shell is interpreting the escape as text when you use `echo` without `echo -e` (or `printf`). It never gets to your program...

Comment: Have you tried not doing `innerloop--;` when you see a \\ ? Currently, when you see a \\, you skip over it and print a \ (as expected), but for some reason you told the computer to go back one character again. Then it sees the second \ in \\ as the first part of a new escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Is the output posted here generated only through 'echo' command from the linux shell or from the program? If it is from the shell, the shell could be treating the escape characters differently.

In which case, the input passed to the program also would differ and thus the outcome/output of your program.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comment, the shell is doing the expansion of escapes.

BusyBox differs from POSIX in several ways; it is unsurprising if the `echo` escaping is one of those.  By the way it does not appear to be a GNU project, so it is just "BusyBox".

Comparing with other shells (including bash 4.2):

```
$ ksh
$ echo "Hello\\nWorld"
Hello\nWorld
$ bash
$ echo "Hello\\nWorld"
Hello\nWorld
$ dash
$ echo "Hello\\nWorld"
Hello
World
```

Further reading:

- [echo(1) and printf(1)](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) (Sven Maschek's page)
- [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)